# Heroku: ! [rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I get and error whenever I try to push rails app to heroku. What do I do to fix this? I did git init, git add ., git commit -m "complete", and git push heroku master

```
To https://git.heroku.com/shuabe.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/james.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone has committed so you have to update your brach width git pull in order to be up to date.

```
git fetch --all --prune
git pull origin master
```

Fetch will update all your branches & pull will grab the latest content into your master branch.

If you would read the error it explaining you what to do.

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes
```

#### More detailed

You are trying to push to a **remote** branch which has some commits that you don't have them locally in your branch. In order to push to a `non-fast-forward` repository you branch must have the latest updates from the remote repository.

#### How to grab latest updates?

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

This command will grab all the content of the whole remote repository and will update the internal git storage (pack & index files) inside the `.git` folder.

```
git pull origin master
```

This command will fetch & merge the remote branch into your local branch (`master`) and after that you will be able to push your changes.

Comment: I got `Fetching origin  - Fetching heroku` - `From github.com:james99x/job
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD  Already up-to-date.
`

Comment: Ok so now pull or merge `git pull origin master`

Comment: I'm getting  `branch master -> FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date.`

Comment: Have you noticed that there are 2 different repos:
`https://git.heroku.com/shuabe.git` & `https://git.heroku.com/james.git`

Comment: Check your .git/config to see to which remote you are trying to push

Comment: Is there a way to merge or at least delete one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79229/discussion-between-codewizard-and-jamesrocky).

Comment: Of course. Come on to the chat and il explain what needs to be done

Answer (score 6):

And also you can use `force` argument.

`git push --force heroku yourbranch:master`

Comment: Sometimes this is the only way to fix. Heroku is letting me down in heaps these days.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed by:

```
git pull heroku master
```

After that, console shows:

```
From https://git.heroku.com/myweb
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging views/layout.hbs
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in views/layout.hbs
Auto-merging views/ads/list.hbs
Auto-merging controllers/users.controller.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in controllers/users.controller.js
Auto-merging config/db.config.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in config/db.config.js
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I accepted every change, and after that:

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 1):

> `git pull heroku main`

Then

> `git push heroku main`

The above commands worked for the question.

- Then I got another error: ***your account has reached its concurrent builds limit (pre-recieve hook declined).***

I resolved that with:

> `heroku restart`

PS: `git pull heroku main` then `git push heroku main` should work straight up for heroku accounts that haven't reached builds limit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).